# Best web app programming platform/ language for someone used to Xcode

Tags: xcode, web-applications

I have learnt to program apps in Xcode and like the environment, especially the interface builder. I want to learn how to code web apps but don't seem to be able to find any similar platform, everything seems to be pretty much purely code based. Any help on where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT want to work with any web app framework that includes an Interface builder. You will get a WYSIWYG mess of code that will be impossible to work with.

You DO want to adopt a web app framework, which makes deploying a web app fast and intuitive. Ruby on Rails is one of the most popular.

Then integrate that that framework with Bootstrap which makes CSS styling a breeze.
http://getbootstrap.com

This would be my recommendation;
1. Pick any framework like Rails(ruby), flask(Python), play!(Java), etc.
2. Learn how to integrate that framework with Bootstrap. If you choose Rails I recommend this tutorial, which teaches you how to integrate bootstrap: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning